# call another controller from dashboard using template pages

Tags: codeigniter

I working on Codeigniter project, I create page template to load header left menu and footer, everything working good, when I try the open link in the menu I want to open another controller. I do it but when the controller view open the variable inside to load database table for each row not working.. but the controller who load the database when I open it without my template its working fine

The Dashboard controller

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{
    protected $data = array();
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data['pagetitle'] = 'Invoices Manager';
  }
  protected function render($the_view)
{
 $this->data['the_view'] = (is_null($the_view)) ? '' : $this->load->view($the_view,$this->data, TRUE);
 $this->load->view('templates/master_page', $this->data); 
}
    public function home() {
        // $this->load->view('templates/master_page', $this->data);
          $this->render( 'templates/homepage_view');
    }
    public function dashboard() {
        // $this->load->view('templates/master_page', $this->data);
          $this->render( 'dashboard/home');
    }
    public function purchaselist(){
         $this->render('purchase/index');
    }     
}
```

The purchase controller that working good alone

```
class Purchase extends CI_Controller{
     protected $data = array();
     protected $mydata = array();  
         function __Construct()
         {
              parent::__Construct ();
                 $this->load->database(); // load database
                 $this->load->model('Purchase_model'); // load model 
                 $this->mydata['purchase']=null;
         }
    public function index()
        {
                 $query = $this->Purchase_model->getPurchaselist();
                     if($query)
        {
            $mydata['purchase'] =  $query;
        }
            $this->load->view('purchase/index', $mydata);
          //  $this->render( 'purchase/index');
        }
}
```

when I call `dashboard/purchaselist`  they say the

> Message: Undefined variable: purchase
>
> Filename: purchase/index.php
>
> Line Number: 17

its should load database table inside the template

Comment: $this->render( 'purchase/index'); not working

Answer (score 0):

try using dashboard/index.php/purchaselist or load your modal `$this->load->model('Purchase_model');` as global

Answer (score 0):

Please pass `null` or empty `array` in purchase if `$query` is empty

```
public function index()
{
   $query = $this->Purchase_model->getPurchaselist();
   if(!empty($query)){
     $mydata['purchase'] =  $query;
   }else{
     $mydata['purchase'] =  array();
   }
   $this->load->view('purchase/index', $mydata);
   //  $this->render( 'purchase/index');
}
```